# BeautifulSoup HTMLParseError. What's wrong with this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib2
url = "http://services.runescape.com/m=news/recruit-a-friend-for-free-membership-and-xp"
res = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BS(res.read())
other_content = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'Content'})[0]
print other_content
```

Yet an error comes up:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py:149: RuntimeWarning: Python's built-in HTMLParser cannot parse the given document. This is not a bug in Beautiful Soup. The best solution is to install an external parser (lxml or html5lib), and use Beautiful Soup with that parser. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser for help.
  "Python's built-in HTMLParser cannot parse the given document. This is not a bug in Beautiful Soup. The best solution is to install an external parser (lxml or html5lib), and use Beautiful Soup with that parser. See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser for help."))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "web.py", line 5, in <module>
    soup = BS(res.read())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py", line 185, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py", line 150, in feed
    raise e
```

I've let two other people use this code, and it works for them perfectly fine. Why is it not working for me? I have bs4 installed...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the error message, one thing you may need to do is install `lxml`, which will provide a more powerful parsing engine for BeautifulSoup to use. See [this](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) section in the docs for a better overview, but the likely reason that it works for two other people is that they have `lxml` (or another parser that handles the HTML properly) installed, meaning that BeautifulSoup uses it instead of the standard built-in (**side note**: your example works for me as well on a system with `lxml` installed, but fails on one without it).

Also, see this note in the docs:

> If you’re using a version of Python 2 earlier than 2.7.3, or a version
>   of Python 3 earlier than 3.2.2, it’s essential that you install lxml
>   or html5lib–Python’s built-in HTML parser is just not very good in
>   older versions.

I would recommend running `sudo apt-get install python-lxml` and seeing if the problem continues.

Comment: @chm It is correct on mine without any change as well, but I have `lxml` installed - when I try it on a system without it I get the same error. The reason is that there is some HTML that is too beastly for the built-in parser to handle (things `lxml` can make better sense of) - when that happens and no better option is available, it fails and you get that error.

Comment: I find bs4/builder/_lxml.py in my bs4 package,but I if I use `import lxml` in my code,I will get ImportError.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tips. I tried typing sudo apt-get install python-lxml but it says "apt-get" command not found.

Comment: Nevermind, I'm using other methods with the link you provided

Comment: @user1915496 Sorry, should have prefaced that with asking if you were on Linux/etc. Let me know if those methods don't sort the problem out and we can try to figure out another approach. Good luck with everything!

Comment: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-2573.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: I am an administrator on this computer (btw I use a mac), and I'm not sure why this isn't working. With pip, this occurs:

Comment: error: could not create '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/html5lib': Permission denied

I definitely am an administrator on this computer. I even checked.

Comment: I have tried pip and easy_install with both html5lib and lxml. Also, sorry for the massive number of comments >.<

Comment: @user1915496 Ha no worries. So first things first - are you running this as `sudo`?

Comment: you'll have to explain further. I'm quite a noob at python :(.

Comment: OH NVM. Yes, I know what you're saying and I hadn't done it before. I am doing it now and it looks good. THANK YOU SO MUCH :D

Comment: @user1915496 No worries - good luck with everything! Feel free to drop a comment back if it doesn't work.